# If I enter [1/0..1/0] on GHCI I am getting Infinite Infinity. Why?

Tags: haskell, infinity

I can't understand the following behavior of ranges in Haskell. Enumerating 1 to 1 gives me a list contain only 1, and 2 to 2 gives me a list contain only 2 as given below.

```
Prelude> [1..1]
[1]
Prelude> [2..2]
[2]
```

But enumerating infinity to infinity gives me a list which is infinite in length and all the elements are infinity, as shown below.

```
Prelude> [1/0..1/0]
[Infinity,Infinity,Infinity,Infinity,Infinity,Infinity,Interrupted.
```

I am aware that Infinity is a concept not to be treated as a number, but what justifies that behavior ?

Comment: This is actually rather more reasonable than many other consequences of IEEE754's non-real-number values.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Haskell's `Double` (the default you get when using `/`) follows the [IEEE 754 standard](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) for floating point numbers, which defines how `Infinity` behaves. This is why `1/0` is `Infinity`.

By this standard (and, to be fair, by logic), `Infinity + 1 == Infinity`, and the `Enum` instance for `Double` just adds `1` each time.

This is another sign that the `Enum` instance for `Double` is not entirely well-formed and does not conform to the expectations we usually have for `Enum` instances. So, as a rule of thumb, you should probably avoid using `..` for floating point numbers: even if *you* understand how it works, it will be confusing for others reading your code. As another example of confusing behavior, consider:

```
Prelude> [0.1..1]
[0.1,1.1]
```

If you want to get into *a lot* more details about the `Enum` instance for `Double`, you can read through this [pretty lengthy Haskell-cafe thread](https://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-September/095431.html).

Comment: Sorry about the accidental downvote—I'll remove it as soon as it's no longer locked in.

Comment: @Slade: Ah, no problem. I added a link to some further reading, so your vote shouldn't be locked in any more.

Answer (score 13):

As Luis Wasserman and Tikhon Jelvis have indicated, the basic problem is that the `Num` and `Enum` instances for `Float` and `Double` are *weird*, and really should not exist at all. In fact, the `Enum` class itself is pretty weird, as it attempts to serve several different purposes at once, none of them well—it is probably best considered a historical accident and a convenience rather than a good example of what a typeclass should look like. The same is true, to a significant extent, of the `Num` and `Integral` classes. When using any of these classes, you must pay close attention to the specific types you are operating on.

The `enumFromTo` methods for floating point are based on the following function:

```
numericEnumFromTo :: (Ord a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> [a]
numericEnumFromTo n m = takeWhile (<= m + 1/2) (numericEnumFrom n)
```

So `2 <= 1+1/2` is *false*, but because of the weirdness of floating point, `infinity <= infinity + 1/2` is *true*.

As Tikhon Jelvis indicates, it's generally best not to use any `Enum` methods, including numeric ranges, with floating point.

Comment: succ. This is exactly the reason there is no `Enum Double` or `Enum Float` in Frege.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the implementation of `[a..b]` continues incrementing `a` by one until it is greater than `b`.  This is never going to happen with infinity, so it goes forever.

I believe your code will probably default to `Double` the way you've written it, which has well-defined semantics for infinity.  IIRC, Haskell follows http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point.